# 3D map view doesn't work in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d

My 3D map view in QGIS goes blank when I try to drape over a DEM raster.  All the data appears fine in the "Flat terrain" view but the desktop goes white when I change the Terrain Type to DEM.  And yes all the data exactly overlays and is valid etc.  There appears to be some postings of the error on a site that will not load but that is all I have found on the subject.

Comment: are there any errors? - it might be the graphics card on your computer.

Comment: Nope no errors.  Quadro P4000 NVIDIA graphics so not new but no slouch either.